# How can I import Excel file (.xlsx) into Azure SQL Database

Tags: excel, import, azure-sql-database

I have data in an Excel file (.xlsx). I have to get this data into Azure SQL Database. Table already exists. I am using Azure Database Studio.

I have tried online query generator but it is mixing up the data.

Comment: I would recommend changing the file to a CSV file, then you can use one of the various methods outlined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Can you use ADF?

Comment: @dark1427 , If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: @NickW No I can't use ADF...

Comment: I found one more approach... By using VBA code in excel we can directly create queries... But that's not suggested for big data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to import Excel file into Azure SQL DB. Below I am showing one approach of using Copy activity in Azure Data Factory.

Sample Excel file with 3 columns.

[image]

SQL DB with table having same 3 fields.

[image]

Use Excel file as Source.

[image]

Use Azure SQL database as Sink.

[image]

For mapping click on Import Schema and do the mapping.

[image]

Finally run pipeline.

**Expected Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhishek... Sorry for late reply... took me some time to try your solution... But it worked... Thanks again...